# Python: Help, function not producing what I want

Tags: python, algorithm, loops

I'm trying to make a collatz sequence that'll print out the numbers continuously as I input the initial integer until it reaches 1 but it's not working quite well.

```
def collatz():
    try:
        number = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
    except ValueError:
        collatz()
    while number != 1:
        if number%2 == 0:
            print(number // 2)
        else:
            print(3 * number + 1)
```

This is what I created and it only returns the value of a single calculation

```
>>> collatz()
Please enter a number: 45
136
>>> collatz()
Please enter a number: 8
4
```

I don't quite understand why this is happening when I want the calculation to go on and keep printing values till it gets to 1(it will always get to 1 that's the trick of the sequence).

Comment: Your code, as posted, will *continually* print the same number, not just once.

Comment: Don't use recursion where iteration will do. Python only supports recursion to a fixed depth, due to its lack of tail-call optimization. Use something like `while True: try: number = int(...) else: break`

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean @chepner

Comment: @Radanek Your function will use an increasing amount of memory for each  incorrect input attempt, and (in the extreme case of 1000 or so failed attempts), actually raise an exception. The `while` loop allows an infinite number of incorrect attempts using a constant amount of memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
def collatz(starting_value):
    value = starting_value

    while value != 1:
        value = (3 * value + 1) if value % 2 else (value // 2)
        yield value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = int(input("Please enter starting value: "))
    print(list(collatz(start)))
```

**Example Run**

```
Please enter starting value: 136
[68, 34, 17, 52, 26, 13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

**How This Works**

This code relies on the use of what are called [*generator functions*](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) - essentially, something that looks like a function but behaves like an iterator. `collatz` is the generator function and on each iteration it will produce the next term in the Collatz sequence.

When we execute the module containing this code directly, the Python interpreter will set its `__name__` variable to `'__main__'`, making the if statement at the bottom true.

Within that if block, we prompt the user for the value to start off the Collatz sequence. We assume they enter a valid number (anything else will cause an unhandled exception to be thrown).

The expression `collatz(start)` will produce a *generator object* that we can *iterate* over. We pass this object directly into `list`, which will keep asking the object to produce its next iteration over and over until it's exhausted. We really hope that Collatz' conjecture is true because otherwise this program might end up running forever!

Collatz' conjecture does seem to hold though, so eventually the while condition `value != 1` becomes false, meaning that the generator object stops producing values. At that point, it will raise `StopIteration` to signal it has no more values, and `list` will return the complete list of Collatz terms that we then print.

The `yield` statement within `collatz` behaves similarly to `return`, except that the calling thread 'remembers' its position - when we ask for the next term in the sequence, it will carry on from that point, using the last stored values for the function's local variables (i.e. `value`).

---

**Printing Terms Vertically**

To print the terms vertically if you'd like, you can just iterate the generator within a for loop and print each term it yields on a new line:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = int(input("Please enter starting value: "))
    for term in collatz(start):
        print(term)
```

**Output**

```
Please enter starting value: 136
68
34
17
52
26
13
40
20
10
5
16
8
4
2
1
```

Comment: I think this is the right solution, maybe just deleting the last `yield value` to avoid a double print of 1 at the end.

Comment: You commented that just as I noticed haha. Thanks for spotting it all the same.

Comment: I like this answer but I'm a beginner and I'm seeing a lot of unusual syntax. However, I'm going for a solution where the answer are printed vertically.

Comment: @Radanek No problem. And about the unfamiliar syntax, I'll update my post with better explanation and ping you again to let you know when that's done if you'd like.

Comment: @Radanek Since this is now the accepted answer and you said you preferred the terms to be printed vertically, I've updated the post to show how that's possible.

Comment: Yes I've simply chosen this one to be the correct answer as I have learnt new techniques and syntax which I perfectly understand.

Answer (score 3):

You never assign any new value to `number`, so the `while` loop is forever True.

Calculate the new value, assign it back to `number`, then print that new value:

```
while number != 1:
    if number % 2 == 0:
        number //= 2
    else:
        number = 3 * number + 1
    print(number)
```

Note that you should not use recursion to get a valid input; use a `while` loop instead. In your case, when the recursive function exits and returns, the code would then go on to the `while` loop with `number` unbound, resulting in an `UnboundLocal` exception.

I'd put asking for the number *outside* the function, perhaps in a new function:

```
def collatz(number):
    while number != 1:
        if number % 2 == 0:
            number //= 2
        else:
            number = 3 * number + 1
        print(number)

def ask_for_number():
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input("Please enter a number: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("That's not a valid number, please try again")

collatz(ask_for_number())
```

Now you can easily test the `collatz()` function independently from asking for a number from the user:

```
>>> collatz(45)
136
68
34
17
52
26
13
40
20
10
5
16
8
4
2
1
```

Comment: I don't understand one thing though. How would an unbound local error occur?

Comment: @Radanek: in your function, only fix the `while` loop. Enter an invalid entry when prompted to `Please enter a number`. Then enter a correct number. The incorrect entry raises a `ValueError` so the `number = ` assignment never executes. You then call `collatz()` again, enter a correct number, the `while` loop (now corrected) cleanly ends and the recursive function call ends. You then return to the previous function at the same point you called `collatz()`, and enter a `while` loop were `number` was never bound, resulting in a `UnboundLocalError`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing that out. I chose the answer using the yield statement as the correct answer because I learnt new syntax. This answer would be my second choice as I now understand that after the recursion ends cleanly, the rest of the initial function call would still run. Y'all are awesome

Comment: @Radanek: and here was me deliberately not using `yield` because I didn't want to overload you an new and more advanced syntax. Oh well, win some, lose some.

Answer (score 2):

```
if number%2 == 0:
    print(number // 2)
else:
    print(3 * number + 1)
```

You're not actually changing the value of number:

```
if number%2 == 0:
    print(number // 2)
    number = number // 2
else:
    print(3 * number + 1)
    number = 3 * number + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to update `number`
Try this :

```
def collatz():
    try:
        number = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
    except ValueError:
        collatz()
    while number != 1:
        if number%2 == 0:
            number = number // 2
            print(number)
        else:
            number = 3 * number + 1
            print(number)
```

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
def collatz():
    try:
        number = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
    except ValueError:
        collatz()
    while number != 1:
        if number %2 ==0:
            number = number // 2
        else:
            number = 3 * number + 1
        print(number)
```

Printing doesn't set the actual value of number!

Answer (score 0):

Several issues:

Main one: You never change the value of `number`.
Therefore your code should keep printing the same number over and over again.

Also you might want to check non-positive numbers.

But also when this is fixed, I suspect some unwanted behaviour when you run into the ValueError you catch.
You call the same function again. After completing this second run, the code will still try to run the next line and fails.

Example:

```py
>>> collatz()
Please enter a number: "foo"
Please enter a number: 4
2
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line 6, in collatz
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'number' referenced before assignment
```

My try to fix all of this:

```py
def collatz():
    number = 0
    while number < 1:
        try:
            number = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
        except ValueError, NameError:
            pass

    while number != 1:
        if number%2 == 0:
            number = number // 2
        else:
            number = 3 * number + 1
        print(number)
```

Comment: Why are you handling a name error and I never got an unbound local error?

Comment: Oh wait I actually did but I don't understand why?

Comment: @Radanek 1) I caught the `NameError` for Python 2.7 support. `input()` already tried to interpret the typed in string.

Comment: @Radanek 2) You type in a string, and catch the resulting NameError where to start *another instance* of `collatz()`. This instance might run completely fine. But after this second instance returned your first instance continues with the next line in (`while number != 1:`). But in *this* instance `number` isn't defined at all. (We tried, but failed.)

Comment: thanks, someone else also pointed out the exact same thing I didn't know the rest of the initial function call would still run after the recursion.